# FileNotFoundException when copying a text file

Tags: java, filereader, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I copied the code below from Lynda Java Essential Training 2016 Episode 70:

```java
    String sourceFile="files/copytest.txt";
    String targetFile="files/copied.txt";

    try(FileReader fReader=new FileReader(sourceFile);
        BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(fReader);
        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(targetFile) ) {

        while(true){

            String line=bReader.readLine();
            if(line==null){
                break;
            }
            else{
                writer.write("jarek"+"\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("File copied succesfull!");

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, it throws the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: files\copytest.txt (The system can not find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.exercise.copyfile.Copyfile.main(Copyfile.java:108)
```

I copied new code to read from txt file:

```
File file = new File("files/copytest.txt");
Scanner in = null;
try {
    in = new Scanner(file);
    String zdanie = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(zdanie);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the result is the same:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: files\copytest.txt (The system can not find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> (Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init> (Unknown Source)
at de.exercise.copyfile.Copyfile.main(Copyfile.java:18)
```

Comment: "The system can not find the path specified" is pretty self-explanatory: The requested file `files/copytest.txt` does not exist (from the working directory point of view).

Comment: First you should do is read the error. It is very straightforward...

Comment: I know that the problem is with my file. But i don't know how fix it. I have a code file in: C:\Users\BYKBRONY\DyskGoogle\workspace\Jarek\src\de\exercise\copyfile and the txt file in:  C:\Users\BYKBRONY\Dysk Google\workspace\Jarek\src\de\exercise\copyfile\files   How chenge it:"files/copytest.txt" to working code?

Comment: What is your _current working directory_ when running your program? Most likely in that you don't have the file `files/copytest.txt`.

Comment: Ok, thanks all, it start search in: C:\Users\BYKBRONY\DyskGoogle\workspace\Jarek so i must add :  src\de\exercise‌​\copyfile/files/copytest.txt and now working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid catching the exceptions with the `Exception`. you should only catch the expected ones.

Second, you said it: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: files\copytest.txt (The system can not find the path specified)`. The `File` instance defined by name only just gets the file in the main folder of the project, thats where it should be.

If you are using NetBeans, it's probably in

> MyDocuments > NetBeanProjects > Projects

Whatever is the project, it should be inside of it in the first level. Something like this:

> C:\MyDocuments\NetBeanProjects\Project\files\copytest.txt

Also, try to put a diferent backslash. You have in the String / instead of .

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: *Programs* can access files on Windows with either slash / or backslash \ -- which BTW disappeared from your answer because it is used for 'markdown' formatting on stackexchange, with some exceptions like code blocks, and comments. It is only in user interfaces -- command line and dialog windows -- that backslash is mandatory. And backslash is harder to use in Java (and C/C++/etc also) because those languages treat it specially and you need to double it.

Comment: I only pointed it because it could be some kind of bug. And thank you for warning me about the backslash is StackOverflow, I didn't know about that. :)